# How do I iterate over all lines of files passed on the commandline in Groovy?

Tags: file, groovy

I want to read whole file contents in groovy on command line.
I am using this code

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy


   def xmlData =""

 System.in.withReader {

        xmlData=xmlData+ it.readLine()

} 

println xmlData
```

and the following command

```
cat 1.xml | /root/a.groovy
```

But it only reads one line from the file. I want to read whole file.

Any suggestion??
Regards
Shuja

Answer (score 2):

```
it.eachLine{ line -> ... }
```

If you don't need to bufferize the whole file in memory just avoid to read it entirely, it will be resource demanding.. I can assure you from tests I had to do :)

Answer (score 2):

To read a line at a time:

```
System.in.eachLine { line ->
    xmlData += line
}
```

Or to read the whole thing in one go:

```
xmlData = System.in.text
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy
def xmlData = System.in.text
println xmlData
```

instead.